# Providing an example of a group $G_1$ and a group $G_2$

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

Can someone please help me with the last part of this problem I am working on? All my work is below. Thank you for your time and help.

Let $N = 10m,$ where $m> 1$ and $5\nmid m.$

i. Let $G_1$ be a group of order $N$ containing $4m$ elements of order 5, and no element of order 10. How do the elements of order 5 divide into conjugacy classes.

$\textit{Proof.}$ Given that the Sylow 5-subgroups are of order 5, we can let $P$ be one of them. Here, the number of Sylow 5-subgroups is $m.$ It follows that $|G: N_G(P)| = m$ and then $|N_G(P)| = 10.$ Since the group $G$ has no elements of order 10, then $C_G(P) = P.$ Thus, $N_G(P)$ contains two classes of conjugate elements of order 5. Then, it follows that $G$ also contains exactly two classes of conjugate elements of order 5. Notice that we use the fact that all Sylow 5-subgroups of $G$ are conjugate to one another.

ii. Let $G_2$ be a group of order $2N$ that contains $4m$ elements of order 5, and no element of order 10. How do the the elements of order 5 divide into conjugacy classes.

$\textit{Proof.}$ By the same process in part i. we see that in this case, we get exactly one conjugacy class of elements of order 5.

iii. How do I provide an example of a group $G_1$ and a group $G_2?$

$\textit{My idea.}$ Can we apply $D_{10}$ to work here for $G_1$? I am not sure about $G_2.$

Comment: $A_5$ works for $G_1$. Have another go at $G_2$ yourself.

Comment: There's an "obvious"  extension of any $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$ ($p=1\mod 5$) by $D_{10}$ which also works.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you for your help! I will think more carefully about $G_2$

Comment: @ancientmathematician for $G_2$?

Comment: I was thinking of a specific example for $G_2$, along similar lines as for the $G_1$ example.

Comment: @DerekHolt yes I am still not sure about the examples, I no longer think $D_{10}$ works

Comment: My example would be a split extension of (the additive group of) $\mathbb{F}_{11}^4$ by the Frobenius group of order $20$: the action of the element of order $5$ being as the diagonal matrix with entries $\zeta, \zeta^2,\zeta^4,\zeta^8$ ($\zeta$ a $5$th rou in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$) and the element of order $4$ permuting cyclically the four $\mathbb{F}_{11}$s.

Comment: But if you wanted a simple example a la @DerekHolt 's example for $G_1$ that's more difficult I think: the smallest Suzuki group looks good and I don't think there are others (?)

Comment: @ancientmathematician The example I was thinking of is easy (rather than simple, but it is almost simple) and closely related to $A_5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh I guessed that but began wondering about how to classify all such groups and in particular simple ones.

Comment: @ancientmathematician $A_7$ is another example. I expect the simple examples could be classified, because any group of sufficiently large Lie rank will have an element of order $10$.